# Is it possible to make some functions used to create a library not available to the caller?

Tags: c, api

I'm writing a library. Say it has two important functions foo1 and foo2.  Both these functions call a third function foo0. But foo0 isn't intended to be used after the library is compiled and being linked to. Is there a way to make foo0 unavailable to the user of the library?

Maybe it's just sanctimonious of me to want to make functions available to the user, but I think it would make for a cleaner library. And I'm pretty sure I've used APIs that do this.

Follow up question: If it is possible, then would I want to create two different header files? One to be used to compile the library, and one with only the the typedefs, enums, prototypes, etc. required by the user?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply declare the function static in the .c file.

Comment: Ahh so _that's_ the point of static functions.  So do people usually make a separate header file that doesn't include prototypes to the static functions?

Comment: Found the second part of my question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689143/best-practice-for-delivering-a-c-api-hiding-internal-functions?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard does not provide means of doing this across multiple translation units. Some linkers provide means to assist with this. With some linkers, you can link several object modules together to produce a combined object module, while instructing the linker to exclude some names from those published by the object module. During the link to produce a combined object module, names that are used on one of the input object modules and defined in another are resolved, so they no longer need to be visible externally.

You would need to specify what developer tools you are using in order to receive further assistance.

Comment: That makes sense. It seems that the best practice for my (small) library is to use static functions and then just have one translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

The best portable way to do this is to randomize the function name at build time and use a preprocessor macro to expose a fixed name to your source files but not in the public header. If the function name is non-descriptive and changes with every build, nobody will try to use it.